# CakePHP : force to download an external file using mediaViews

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I'm working on an application using cakephp and I want to force a jpeg download.

So far, so good, by using mediaViews... but the file is'nt hosted on the server because i'm using a soap webservice and I just get a full jpeg file url.
Is there a way to use mediaViews in cakePHP with an external link such as `http://mywebsite.com/foo/bar/picture.jpeg` without download it before saving it on the cakephp webroot folder?

Sorry for my poor english, I try to do my best...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot force an object you don't have control over to be downloaded. This is because the headers that make it downloadable (`'Content-disposition: attachment'`) are set by the responding server. For example, if I tried to force download an image from Google there's no way for me to set the headers on it.

Comment: So the only way to do it is to download it in a temp folder before, then force download and delete it?
There is another problem: how to detect the end of downloads to delete the file...

Comment: To detect the download is complete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905664/detect-if-download-is-complete

Comment: @bgondy yep, that's the only way. Also thanks for the link @Alex!

Comment: Thanks! I was also wondering if downloading the file using curl and send the content to the client (using base64 for example) with the required header but without writing it on the server was possible.