# Download multiple files with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im aware that it is not possible to download multiple files using the same windows as HTTP does not allow it.

But I managed to do it using the code below:

```
$('#test').on("click",function(e){
    window.location="getEmployeeInstructions.php"; 
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location="getMergedEmployeeReports.php"; }, 10000);
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location="getQualityHandbook.php"; }, 20000);
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location="getEquipmentReport.php"; }, 30000);   
    return false;
});
```

Not a very clean or usefull way to do it, as it requires each download to be done before the next one can execute.

So i was thinking. Is there a way to be notified when a file has been downloaded and initiate the next file download instead of using the setTimeout function to postpone each download ? That way i can at least notify the user of the progress and make him aware that the page is working on his request..

**Update:** Being notified is not a requirement for me if im able to start multiple downloads at once and not forced to start the next download once the previous file was completed.

Comment: Why not just zip up the files and download the zip?

Comment: That is possible, but the users are to be considered "VERY" bad computer skill wise and should not be presented with another tool to unzip the content..

Comment: so you are trying to detect if download is complete - try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905664/detect-if-download-is-complete

Comment: @Demodave Looks like they are describing a solution for java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just solve similar task today. Use src attribute of hidden iframe. Its handle file downloading without parent page changing. And this way will not be blocked as multiply popups.

```
 <iframe id="downloader1" style="display:none"></iframe>
 <iframe id="downloader2" style="display:none"></iframe>
 <iframe id="downloader3" style="display:none"></iframe>

$('#test').on("click",function(e){
    $("#downloader1").attr("src", "file1.php");
    $("#downloader2").attr("src", "getQualityHandbook.php");
    $("#downloader3").attr("src", "getEquipmentReport.php"); 
    return false;
});
```

One addition. When getQualityHandbook.php return error instead file, maybe you vant to handle this situation:

```
$('#downloader2').unbind().load( function()
    {//handle if not file received
        var data = $('#downloader2').contents().find('body ').html();
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: So i guess i need to make an iframe for EACH download to execute all downloads at once ? .. otherwise i will not get rid of my delayed execution ?

Comment: Yes, i have no way to test it right now, but 4 iframes should download 4 files at one time. Good idea. : )

Comment: As a side note display should be set to none. And it does not fire my downloads at all ?

Comment: Sorry, "src" instead "href". My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').on("click",function(e){
    window.open("getEmployeeInstructions.php", 'download1'); 
    window.open("getMergedEmployeeReports.php", 'download2');
    window.open("getQualityHandbook.php", 'download3');
    window.open("getEquipmentReport.php", 'download4');   
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That would be a solution but not a very sleek one. AND Chrome automatically opens a URL in a new tab only if it's user generated action, limited to one tab per user action. In any other case, the URL will be opened in a new window (which, BTW, is blocked by default on Chrome

Comment: Sorry, I mocked it up quickly and it worked for me.  Opened new windows, downloaded the file, and closed the windows automatically.  Only thing is I had to do was allow popups.  Not a big deal for a corporate website.